# Необходимо сбрасывать кнопкой оба значения radiobutton bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Подскажите как сбросить оба значения с помощью кнопки в этом коде по ссылке -

http://jsfiddle.net/9o41oykp/34/

```js
$(function () {
    $('.button-checkbox').each(function () {

        // Settings
        var $widget = $(this),
            $button = $widget.find('button'),
            $checkbox = $widget.find('input:radio'),
            color = $button.data('color'),
            settings = {
                on: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check'
                },
                off: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked'
                }
            };

        // Event Handlers
        $button.on('click', function () {
            $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
            $checkbox.triggerHandler('change');
            updateDisplay();
        });

        // Actions
        function updateDisplay() {
            $('.button-checkbox').each(function () {
                var isChecked = $(this).find('input:radio').is(':checked');
                // Set the button's state
                $(this).find('button').data('state', (isChecked) ? "on" : "off");
                // Set the button's icon
                $(this).find('button').find('.state-icon')
                    .removeClass()
                    .addClass('state-icon ' + settings[$(this).find('button').data('state')].icon);
                // Update the button's color
                if (isChecked) {
                    $(this).find('button')
                        .removeClass('btn-default')
                        .addClass('btn-' + color + ' active');
                } else {
                    $(this).find('button')
                        .removeClass('btn-' + color + ' active')
                        .addClass('btn-default');
                }
            })
        }
        // Initialization
        function init() {
            updateDisplay();
            // Inject the icon if applicable
            if ($button.find('.state-icon').length == 0) {
                $button.prepend('<i class="state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon + '"></i> ');
            }
        }
        init();
    });
});
$('#reset').click(function() {
        $('.button-checkbox').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-check glyphicon-unchecked');
});
```

```html
<span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg" data-color="primary">Option 1</button>
        <input type="radio" class="xhidden" name="group1" id="op1" checked />
</span>
<span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg" data-color="primary">Option 2</button>
        <input type="radio" class="xhidden" name="group1" id="op2"  />
</span>

<br><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="reset">Reset<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: В вашем коде кнопка `Reset` переключает иконки на кнопках. Поясните, что имеете в виду под словами `сбрасывать оба значения`?

Comment: т.е. если нажал на кнопку "check", убрал "uncheck", мне нужно чтобы "reset" сбрасывал значения до "uncheck" и убирал цвет независимо, где "check".

Comment: Спасибо Глеб..)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы по нажатию на <kbd>Reset</kbd> убрать галочки из иконок и сделать все кнопки серыми:

1. находим иконки с классом `.glyphicon-check`;
2. лишаем окраски их родителей;
3. сами иконки заменяем на иконки без галочки.

```js
$('#reset').click(function() {
    /* 1. */
    var $icon = $('.button-checkbox .glyphicon-check');

    /* 2. */
    var $button = $icon.parent();
    $button.removeClass('btn-' + $button.data('color') + ' active').addClass('btn-default');

    /* 3. */
    $icon.removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
});

$(function () {
    $('.button-checkbox').each(function () {

        // Settings
        var $widget = $(this),
            $button = $widget.find('button'),
            $checkbox = $widget.find('input:radio'),
            color = $button.data('color'),
            settings = {
                on: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check'
                },
                off: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked'
                }
            };

        // Event Handlers
        $button.on('click', function () {
            $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
            $checkbox.triggerHandler('change');
            updateDisplay();
        });

        // Actions
        function updateDisplay() {
            $('.button-checkbox').each(function () {
                var isChecked = $(this).find('input:radio').is(':checked');
                // Set the button's state
                $(this).find('button').data('state', (isChecked) ? "on" : "off");
                // Set the button's icon
                $(this).find('button').find('.state-icon')
                    .removeClass()
                    .addClass('state-icon ' + settings[$(this).find('button').data('state')].icon);
                // Update the button's color
                if (isChecked) {
                    $(this).find('button')
                        .removeClass('btn-default')
                        .addClass('btn-' + color + ' active');
                } else {
                    $(this).find('button')
                        .removeClass('btn-' + color + ' active')
                        .addClass('btn-default');
                }
            })
        }
        // Initialization
        function init() {
            updateDisplay();
            // Inject the icon if applicable
            if ($button.find('.state-icon').length == 0) {
                $button.prepend('<i class="state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon + '"></i> ');
            }
        }
        init();
    });
});
```

```html
<span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg" data-color="primary">Option 1</button>
        <input type="radio" class="xhidden" name="group1" id="op1" checked />
</span>
<span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg" data-color="primary">Option 2</button>
        <input type="radio" class="xhidden" name="group1" id="op2"  />
</span>

<br><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="reset">Reset<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```